# Select Different values from different tables based on id's with one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello I would like to ask how I can select different values from different tables based on the id's from my main table `properties` table:

Here is how my DB is organized:

```
propery table:

----------------------------------------------------
id | title | property_type | city | sector | owner | 
----------------------------------------------------
1  | title | 1             | 2    | 6      | 12    |
----------------------------------------------------



property_type table: 

--------------
id | english |
--------------
1  | name    |
--------------
2  | name 2  |
--------------



owner table:

-----------------------------------
id | ownername | phone            |
-----------------------------------
12 | Mike      | 27836            |
-----------------------------------
```

So my main select command is: `'SELECT id, title, property_type, owner FROM properties ORDER BY id'`

**Where for example in owner I have to be able to select both parameters the `ownername` and `phone`**

Which is dumping the different ID's but I wold like to modify this query so it selects the values from the different tables based on the id in the main table.

Any help achieving this will be appreciated. And the Select should be realized with a single query.

**the Result of the query should be: 
id(property table),english(property_type table), ownername (owner table:), phone (owner table).**

Comment: Can you add some sample data and results? I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: `InnerJoin` the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select p.id, p.title, p.property_type, o.ownername, o.phone, pt.english
from property p join property_type pt 
on p.property_type = pt.id
join owner o
on o.id = p.owner
```

You would just `join` the tables. Add more columns if needed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is the query you want:

```
SELECT
   P.id
  ,PT.english
  ,O.ownername
  ,O.phone
FROM property P
JOIN property_type PT
  ON PT.id = P.property_type
JOIN owner O
  ON O.id = P.owner
```

[SQLFiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f183/1/0)